# performance boost by seemingly unnecessary string initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, string, initialization, .net-2.0

At the moment I maintain a quirky codebase, and came across the following same pattern more than 100 times:

```
string NotMySqlQuery = ""; //why initialize the string with "", only to overwrite it on the next line?
NotMySqlQuery = "The query to be executed";
```

Since I came across this so often, I now doubt my own good judgement.

Is this a trick to optimize the compiler or does it bring any other advantages?

It reminds me a bit of the old times when I did write some code in C++, but it still doesn't look like proper dealing with strings to me.

Why would someone write code like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance advantage of that syntax. It is even slightly worse than not initializing it at all, since the strings are immutable in c# and this way 2 separate strings are allocated.

Comment: I know that strings are immutable in C#, but many times the "" string is assigned, and it only exists 1 time in the "string-repository" of .NET, right? That's why I thought maybe this could really be some trick :)

Comment: the default value for a string is null, so assigning another value to it is an unnecessary operation. No trick there, you can't reserve space for the new string or anything like that...

Comment: thank you. Now I feel less guilty refactoring those unnecessary steps :)

Answer (score 1):

For your simple case, it is better to save the 2 lines into one, there is no point to assign it an empty string, and immediately assign another value to it.

```
string NotMySqlQuery = "The query to be executed";
```

This is clearer.

Comment: the crazy thing is, almost all cases, where this structure are used in the code, are that simple.

Comment: you can perform a regex search and convert the crazy pattern in one batch using find and replace.